# Google Spreadsheet: Sum daily sales total

Tags: countif, sumifs

Trying to figure out how to sum up daily totals bases on a date in 1 column and empty cells below until the next date. Column A has the dates and Column C has the revenue. I thought I could run it down column D displaying the SUM of column C from the date until the last empty cell.

In this example D2 should return $5617.82, D4 should return $5455.84, etc

I'll openly admit I am not the spreadsheet guru the office folk profess me to be. I'm out of ideas.

[Example of spreadsheet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uOSi.jpg)

Comment: It would help if we had the row and column number in your example spedreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

there is no way I can think of to do that without having the date on each row, like a good formatted spreadsheet.

if you really can not repeat the date on each row (for ease of visual use), you could make a (hidden) row with an if. by example, if the date are in column A and the hidden row is column B, for the second row :

`IF(A2<>""; A2; B1)`

this formula will take the value at is left if there is one, and the value above is there is none.

Once you have this row, you can do a normal sumif.
if you want to have the sum in cell D2 and D4 but not in cell D3, I would do a sumif who compare value in column A and in the hidden row (should be B, with B-C-D now shifted right to be C-D-E).

the sumif would look like `=SUMIF(B2:B20, A2, E1:E10)`

Comment: I have the date only once because I'm using it to count days of the month in a couple other formulas. I supposed I could rewrite those to count the unique dates.  

Thanks. I'm going to try this this evening.